# Downloading large amount of data from a secure link

Tags: file-download

I've received a secure link to a directory on a client's SharePoint for the purpose of sharing a non-trivial amount of data, probably about 30GB. I can download single directories and it works, but it's a chore having to click everything and I will need to do that often. I tried downloading it all by selecting every top-level directory and clicking "Download", but the file that gets downloaded is corrupted — ZIP reports missing central directory, so I assume it's truncated during download. The "Open in File Explorer" link returns Access Denied. Are there any other options for automating download of this directory?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of SharePoint you have you can try to sync the library using OneDrive.  If it is a option you should see a "Sync" button in the library.